# Are there humans in the Octonauts universe?

Tags: octonauts

In the *Octonauts* episode *The Great Swamp Search*, when Ranger Marsh is asked how invasive species arrived in the Everglades, he responds:

> Different ways. **Some were pets** and got loose, some were stowaways and on ships. But one thing's for sure: they all cause a lot of problems.

<sub>https://octonauts.fandom.com/wiki/The_Great_Swamp_Search/transcript</sub>

This question is very lovingly, playfully, tongue-in-cheek: **are there humans in the *Octonauts* universe?** Otherwise, how could any animal be a *pet* since everyone in *Octonauts* is an anthropomorphized animal?

---

*(Realistically, I know: this is just the show's writers slipping in a tidbit of child-comprehensible real-world trivia without hyper-vigilance on how the semantics of the sentence might play out to adults contemplating the pet/owner relationship in an anthropomorphized universe -- I just thought this might be fun to see how "Octonauts" and/or in-universe-consistency enthusiasts might explain this)*

Comment: There are no humans in the Octonauts universe. It's perfectly possible to have pets though, as some animals have subhuman intelligence

Comment: Other important Octonauts questions 1) What kind of penguin is Peso supposed to be anyway? 2) Where do Shellington and Professor Inkling sleep? 3) Come to think about it, what's up with the internal layout of the Octopod anyway? How do they fit both the library and the launch bay in? 4)...

Comment: Aren't the Vegemals pets?

Comment: @AJFaraday This is triggering deeper thoughts than I anticipated...are the Vegemals _pets_? FWIW, I'd never viewed them as _pets_, I'd always thought of them as peers of the Octonauts...in the sense that they appear to be sapient beings.

Comment: You make a fair point, I've a vague memory of the them doing some advanced tasks such as preparing meals and saving Christmas. They have a sort of babble that the others don't understand, but maybe it's just a different language. Which is strange because literally every other creature in the world seems to share a language.

Answer (score -3):

The reason that theirs like no humans in octonauts is because the octonauts and the octo agents and etc are takeing place of humans like for a example, tweak is a human so yeah the octonauts are humans and the reason that Ranger marsh says that some were pets and got loose and some were stowaways on ships is idk but yeah the octonauts and etc are humans and all other humans are like the octonaugts.

Comment: If you're going to assert that there are no humans in _Octonauts_, you should provide some evidence for that, rather than just the assertion itself. Also, if you can't explain what Ranger Marsh meant by _"some were pets"_, then you can't really answer this question properly, since an explanation for that is precisely what was being asked for.

Comment: Tweak T. Bunny most certainly isn't a human. She's a rabbit.